# Format Decimal value to string prefixed by a minus sign

Tags: c#

How do I convert a decimal value to a string of decimal digits (0-9), prefixed by a minus sign?

Decimal paymentAmt = -871.00M;

I need it formatted to: -000000871.00

The format parameter can be any valid standard numeric format specifier except for D, R, and X, as well as any combination of custom numeric format specifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ToString` to format it, check out MSDN for [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

```
var paymentAmtFormatted = paymentAmt.ToString("000000000.00");
Console.WriteLine(paymentAmtFormatted);
```

The above prints the following to the `Console`:

> -000000871,00

I am using the [Zero Placeholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0):

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present;
>   otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! No problem, don't forget to mark answers as accepted answer if it is the answer that solved your problem.